# How to retrieve Avro data from HDFS?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I've created a JSON data, and an Avro schema for it:

```
{"username":"miguno","tweet":"Rock: Nerf paper, scissors is fine.","timestamp": 1366150681 }
{"username":"BlizzardCS","tweet":"Works as intended.  Terran is IMBA.","timestamp": 1366154481 }
```

and

> > {   "type" : "record",   "name" : "twitter_schema",   "namespace" : "com.miguno.avro",   "fields" : [ {
> >         "name" : "username",
> >         "type" : "string",
> >         "doc"  : "Name of the user account on Twitter.com"   }, {
> >         "name" : "tweet",
> >         "type" : "string",
> >         "doc"  : "The content of the user's Twitter message"   }, {
> >         "name" : "timestamp",
> >         "type" : "long",
> >         "doc"  : "Unix epoch time in seconds"   } ],   "doc:" : "A basic schema for storing Twitter messages" }

I then converted it to Avro as follows:

```
java -jar ~/avro-tools-1.7.4.jar fromjson --schema-file twitter.avsc twitter.json > twitter.avro
```

Put the file on hdfs with this:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal twitter.avro <path>
```

And then In Spark CLI I issued the code:

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.mapred.{AvroInputFormat, AvroWrapper}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable

val path = "hdfs:///path/to/your/avro/folder"
val avroRDD = sc.hadoopFile[AvroWrapper[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]](path)
```

However when doing:

```
avroRDD.first
```

I'm facing the following exception:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 2.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 13) had a not serializable result:
>   org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)

What is a solution to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark is trying to ser/de your avro data but it is not "java serializable" (default ser. used in spark).

You have a couple alternatives:

- extract the generic record from the wrapper and map each record to some serializable structure
- generate specific record classes and deser to them instead of generic records (you will still need to extract the record from the wrapper)
- enable kryo serialization (this would work in **some cases only**)

Note that the records are reused internally, thus if you do for example a rdd.collect you will end up with all records having same values. Mapping the raw input data to something else before doing the collect solves the problem as you are doing a copy.